# Check if gps is on In Kitkat (4.4)

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Below kitkat, I get if gps is on with providers list

```
String providers = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(providers)) {
    return false;
}
return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

But in kitkat, Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED is deprecated.

Javaodc say "use Secure.LOCATION_MODE", Location modes are belows...

```
Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF
Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY
Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING
Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY
```

But i do not know exactly below code is correct. (I do not have kitkat devices)

```
int locationMode = Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
boolean isGpsOn = locationMode != Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF;
```

If incorrect, Answer correct code please.

EDIT

I know LocationManager. But It require ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission. 
I do not need to "Access" location.

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );
boolean isGpsOn = manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )
```

Comment: Your code is correct. You also can use emulator to try some 4.4 futures.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Self Answer

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static boolean isGpsEnabled(Context context) {

    if (PackageUtil.checkPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        String providers = Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(providers)) {
            return false;
        }
        return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } else {
        final int locationMode;
        try {
            locationMode = Secure.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Secure.LOCATION_MODE);
        } catch (SettingNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        switch (locationMode) {

        case Secure.LOCATION_MODE_HIGH_ACCURACY:
        case Secure.LOCATION_MODE_SENSORS_ONLY:
            return true;
        case Secure.LOCATION_MODE_BATTERY_SAVING:
        case Secure.LOCATION_MODE_OFF:
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And Add this method in your packageutils class :

```
public static class PackageUtil {

    static boolean checkPermission(Context context, String accessFineLocation) {

        int res = context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(accessFineLocation);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, I got the same issue. But your code isn't solving the problem I got :-/ my Nexus5 will show every time I check the settings my dialog to enable gps...

Comment: PackageUtil gives error . please correct or provide suggestion