# Enabling GPS in Android

Tags: android, gps

I am using GPS location in my app, but when GPS is not enable app crashed.
as I am a newbie to android develpment, I googled this and I found this answer in Stackoverflow
[Check if gps is on In Kitkat (4.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21876191/check-if-gps-is-on-in-kitkat-4-4)

The problem here is that PackageUtil & ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION are undefined and I am not sure which library I should download and embed to my app

Any suggestions?

```
if (PackageUtil.checkPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
```

Comment: Could you please post the Logcat at the time of Crash.

Comment: its syntax error "cannot resolve symbol PackageUtil" and "cannot resolve symbol ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a permission in Android, you have to do it in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

It should be declared after the closing of the `<application>` tag.

Read more about it in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

**UPDATE**

You can check whether gps is enabled or not like this

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Enabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is Disabled in your devide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And to show the GPS settings page you can use

```
Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
```

Comment: its already there     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

Comment: then why are you using that `if` loop..i mean, what is the purpose?

Comment: This is the code to check for enabling GPS in the example I posted with the question

Answer (score 1):

First add this permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Remove the if code you have written.

Then add this GPS checker code. This code checks whether GPS is enabled or not. If it is not enabled it will open the GPS settings.

```
private void CheckEnableGPS() {
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
        if(!provider.equals("")){
            //GPS Enabled
        }else{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Enable GPS");  // GPS not found
            builder.setMessage("The app needs GPS to be enabled do you want to enable it in the settings? "); // Want to enable?
            builder.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.create().show();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED is obsolete. thats why there is a check for Kitkat in the example I used.

Comment: It works fine on lollipop give it a shot if it doesn't work out lets see